# Real Analysis: Derivative of the function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Find *k* such that the function $f(x)=|x|^3$ is $C^{k}$ but not $C^{k+1}$

I am SO lost...any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well,
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^3 &\text{if $x \geq 0$}\\
-x^3 &\text{if $x < 0$}.
\end{cases}
$$
So you are gluing two function at $x=0$: the derivatives of the two pieces are $3x^2$, $6x$, $6$, on the right, and $-3x^2$, $-6x$, $-6$ on the left. Higher derivatives are identically zero.
Now the question is: how manu derivatives can you glue at zero, so that the gluing is continuous? The answer is not very difficult.

Comment: Wow...I had a major brain fart there! Thanks for the clarification, I am embarrassed.